# How to Return List<t> as obect in .net webapi

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple controller and action in WEBAPI from where i am returning a list of class.

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            List<Product> objList = new List<Product>
            {
            new Product() {id = 1,details = "Test1"},
             new Product() {id = 2,details = "Test2"}
            };

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, objList);
        }
    }
```

Output of this on Postman is a JSON Array looks like this

```
[   {
    "id": 1,
    "details": "Test1"   },   {
    "id": 2,
    "details": "Test2"   } ]
```

But i don't want it to retutn it as a JSON Array instead i want to return as a Array object,

```
> {[   {
>     "id": 1,
>     "details": "Test1"   },   {
>     "id": 2,
>     "details": "Test2"   } ]}
```

How can we achieve this in webAPI

Comment: I believe that web-api supports only two type of response json or xml.

Comment: where are you using this output in and why do you want Array Object? output json if deserialize is a list.

Comment: Its require in some Android App..

Comment: what you want to produce is not a valid JSON, go to http://www.jslint.com and check.